# How to combine factor levels in R to fixed number of groups?

Tags: r

I want to combine the levels of a factor so that I have a fixed number of groups with similar number of observations. While there is the `forcats::fct_lump` function, this aggregates only the least or most common levels together. In my case I need to order the factor levels on the values of another column and can only combine levels with a similar mean value in that column.

This is the algorithm I developed:

- Order the factor by the mean value of the other column.
- Loop over the factor levels, if the number of observations is smaller than some threshold, combine factor levels, else start new group.

But how do I choose the threshold so that I end up with a fixed number of groups? And groups are filled with similar number of observations if possible?

Also it would be better to take account of the difference in mean values when combining instead of only using the order.

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
set.seed(12)

# Generate some data
df <- data.table(a = sample(letters, 100, replace = TRUE),
                 b = sample(1:20, 100, replace = TRUE))

df <- 
  df[, .(mean_b = mean(b), 
         freq_a = .N / NROW(df)), a] %>%
  .[order(mean_b)]


group = 1
group.prop = 0
for (i in seq_len(NROW(df))) {

  # Add to group if number of observations in group does not exceed some threshold
  if (i > 1 && (group.prop + df[i, freq_a]) > 1 / 10) {
    group <- group + 1
  }

  df[i, a_group := group]
  group.prop <- df[a_group == group, sum(freq_a)]
}

df

# Show proportion of observations per group
df[, sum(freq_a), a_group]
# a_group   V1
# 1:       1 0.07
# 2:       2 0.07
# 3:       3 0.08
# 4:       4 0.10
# 5:       5 0.08
# 6:       6 0.06
# 7:       7 0.08
# 8:       8 0.03
# 9:       9 0.09
# 10:      10 0.08
# 11:      11 0.10
# 12:      12 0.07
# 13:      13 0.09
```

Comment: What do you mean by `groups are filled with similar number of observations` ? So are you trying to create groups in such a way that their `mean` is the same ? Also what would be your ideal expected output?

Comment: The `mean` inside each group should be similar. What I mean with "similar number of observations" is that it is not desirable to have groups with only 1 observation and other groups with 1 million observations. This could currently happen with the algorithm above. The desired output would be a grouping where the groups are of similar size and I can easily control for the number of groups

Comment: Ah sorry, you misunderstood me. I want to combine levels of column `a` which have a similar mean value. For example levels `q` and `x` have a similar value, so could be grouped together to a new group `group1`. So, levels with similar mean values end up in one new group. The mean values of the new groups themselves are as different as possible. Thereby I do not want that group sizes are too different and want to control for the number of groups.